# How to correct colors when scanning bleached Polaroids?

Tags: film, polaroid, negative-scanner

I bleached the back of a `Polaroid` that comes from `Fuji FP-100C` by pouring toilet bleach materials on the back of the Polaroid film to wash it off so it becomes a negative that light passes through it.  It sometimes creates interesting effects cooler than the Polaroid itself.

But when I scan it, the colors are coming out wrong and different from the original photo that got developed automatically. My scanner is `Epson V-600`, and I used `SilverFast` software and the Epson scan that comes free.

Is the color something I should fix while scanning? Or just in general what are some nuances I should be aware of for this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blog had good information for scanning negatives, not Polaroids but still:

http://www.sebastian-schlueter.com/blog/2016/5/8/scanning-color-negative-film

In summary: The scanning software has profiles for different types of negative film we should pick, then next step is to go and manually in the software play with Histogram and specially the tones and the diagram for global color change. ... and then next step is to add the contrast back. All done in the software.

Comment: Well this isn't sold or marketed as a negative film. It's an instant positive, and the negative described is more of an "alt process" creation. So there won't be a profile. Best thing for the OP is to set white balance based on a white or neutral gray in the scene, and let the remaining colors fall where they may. Also, I've tried contact printing these negatives and the colors don't resolve in the same way the positive appears, so expect some shifts and differences in contrast. But that's what people enjoy about it.

Comment: @bvy OK I was under impression that I can give the positives to the model and keep the negatives and use those for myslef and looking the same as the positives... so I should NOT do that .. looks like it is best to scan the positives... I thought they are equal